# How to nest / unnest data frames in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Does Julia have any analogues of the `nest` and `unnest` functions from the [tidyr R package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html)? Particularly, is there a way to make efficient nesting / unnesting operations using DataFrames.jl?

Comment: Can you describe a concrete use case? Note that nesting happens automatically if a transformation (e.g. `transform`) returns a `DataFrame`. But often nesting isn't needed since you can iterate over the result of `groupby` to perform operations on `SubDataFrame`s, or use `combine` to apply an operation to them and store the result.

Comment: I'd like to sample rows in a `DataFrame` by group. And the number of rows is different for different groups. In this case, I need both a `SubDataFrame` and a single integer (not array) for each operation so it would be nice if both a `SubDataFrame` and an integer (for the number of rows in a sample) were in one row.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following `DataFrame`:

```
julia> d = DataFrame(g=[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,], val1=1:7, val2 = 'a':'g')
7×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ g     │ val1  │ val2 │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Char │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 1     │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ 1     │ 2     │ 'b'  │
│ 3   │ 1     │ 3     │ 'c'  │
│ 4   │ 2     │ 4     │ 'd'  │
│ 5   │ 2     │ 5     │ 'e'  │
│ 6   │ 3     │ 6     │ 'f'  │
│ 7   │ 3     │ 7     │ 'g'  │
```

and assume that you want to sample one element from each group defined by the `g` column.
This can be achieved by:

```
julia> DataFrame([rand(eachrow(gr)) for gr in groupby(d,:g)])
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ g     │ val1  │ val2 │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Char │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │ 'b'  │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 4     │ 'd'  │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │ 'f'  │
```

Hope this is what you need.

#### EDIT

If you want a different element count from each group you could do something like this:

```
julia> g_to_rows=Dict(1=>4,2=>3,3=>7);   # desired element counts

julia> [ gr[rand(1:nrow(gr),g_to_rows[gr.g[1]]), :] for gr in groupby(d,:g)]
3-element Array{DataFrame,1}:
 4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ g     │ val1  │ val2 │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Char │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 1     │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ 1     │ 1     │ 'a'  │
│ 3   │ 1     │ 3     │ 'c'  │
│ 4   │ 1     │ 2     │ 'b'  │
 3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ g     │ val1  │ val2 │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Char │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ 5     │ 'e'  │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │ 'e'  │
│ 3   │ 2     │ 5     │ 'e'  │
 7×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ g     │ val1  │ val2 │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Char │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 3     │ 7     │ 'g'  │
│ 2   │ 3     │ 6     │ 'f'  │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │ 'f'  │
│ 4   │ 3     │ 7     │ 'g'  │
│ 5   │ 3     │ 7     │ 'g'  │
│ 6   │ 3     │ 6     │ 'f'  │
│ 7   │ 3     │ 6     │ 'f'  │
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the point is that I need to sample different number of rows from different groups. This is where nesting comes handy since the required number of rows to sample from each group may be represented as a single value per row of nested data frame.

Comment: Just to make my idea clearer:
`DataFrame(
    g = 1:3, 
    data_to_sample_from = [
        (DataFrame(val1=1:3, val2='a':'c')), 
        DataFrame(val1=4:5, val2='d':'e'), 
        DataFrame(val1=6:7, val2='f':'g')
    ],
    required_number_of_rows = [4, 3, 7]
)`
Here sampling may be a rowwise operation.

Comment: OK here you go!

Comment: What if there are several variables defining a group? In my case, data on the number of rows that need to be selected from each group is stored in a separate data frame How do I create a dictionary like in your example from a data frame? And is it worth it? I mean It seems simpler just to join two data frames.

Comment: It depends on the use case. You can always iterate over the groups. I was trying to make it a one-liner.